# What's the deal with the election badges?

Tags: support, election, badges

Why did everyone who participated in the election a few months back earn the appropriate badges yesterday?

- [Election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election), which shows the date range of the election. Started Jan 23, ended Feb 7.
- [Caucus badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/88/caucus), see that everyone earned it 1 day ago (at time of writing).
- [Constituent badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/89/constituent), again everyone earned it 1 day ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the Caucus and Constituent badges are [brand new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135144/what-should-the-election-voting-badge-be-named), but they have been awarded retroactively to cover previous elections on each of the sites.

You can read more about them [on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/?cb=1).

Comment: Beat me to it...